# variable is not assigned in for loop despite EnableDelayedExpansion

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, return-value

I have the following batch script that is supposed to generate filenames on the fly. Unfortunately I can't get the function to assign a return value to `filename`. Each echo returns an empty line.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /l %%i in (0,1,1) do (
    call :create_filename %%i filename
    echo(!%filename%!
)
pause

:create_filename
    set "base=My test file"
    if %1 GTR 0 set "base=%base% (%1)"
    set "%~2=%base%.txt"
GOTO :eof
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using delayed variables require you to refer to them with `!Var!` syntax rather than %Var% syntax. `%Var%` remains expanded at readtime. `!Var!` are expanded at execution time. `Set DelayedExpansion` just turns on support for`!Var!`.

Comment: Damn. So simple. Thanks!